# How to get and set value for a key in json whose node path is dynamically known during run time only?

Tags: java, json

Suppose I have a json as below:

```
{
   "key0":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":{
         "key3":[
            {
               "key4":"value2",
               "key5":"value3"
            },
            {
               "key4":"value4",
               "key5":"value5"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I would know the node path of key4 only during runtime as `key0/key2/key3[]/key4`.
 How can I get values of key4 and change specific node value of key4 with java?

Comment: What sort of library are you using to read this file? Gson? JSONObject?

Comment: You could pass this path as an argument of your java program and you read it when you need it. Something like `java My program.java key0/key2/key3[]/key4`?

Comment: Is the structure of your json itself is dynamic?

Comment: I am using JSONObject library. Yes, the structure of json itself is dynamic.